# Spring batch skips records

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch (3.0.4.RELEASE) job configured to index some records in solr. I'm not experiencing any exceptions and the job responds as completing successfully, however on occasion it is only processing around half of the records in the database. I have configured a `JdbcCursorItemReader` and custom writer, as shown below.

```
<batch:job-repository id="jobRepository"
                      data-source="dataSource"
                      transaction-manager="transactionManager"
                      isolation-level-for-create="DEFAULT"
                      table-prefix="BATCH_"
                      max-varchar-length="1000"/>

<bean id="myItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="sql" value="SELECT id FROM my_item ORDER BY id asc"/>
    <property name="rowMapper" ref="myItemIdRowMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
    <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="4"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jobLauncher" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
    <property name="taskExecutor" ref="taskExecutor"/>
</bean>

<batch:job id="myItemIndexJob" restartable="true" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="executionListener"/>
    </batch:listeners>
    <batch:step id="myItemSolrIndexStep" allow-start-if-complete="true">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="myItemReader" writer="myItemSolrWriter" commit-interval="50"/>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

The row mapper simply returns the id from the query

```
public final class MyItemRowMapper implements RowMapper<Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        return rs.getInt("id");
    }

}
```

And the writer hands off to a service to index in solr. The writer does not modify MyItem.

```
public class MyItemSolrWriter implements ItemWriter<Integer> {

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends Integer> myItemIds) throws Exception {
        service.index(Lists.newArrayList(myItemIds));
    }
}
```

This is the `step_execution` database entry for the job run which indicates that it hasn't skipped anything and has read only `279086` rows

```
|     step_name            | start_time              | end_time                | status    | read_count | filter_count | write_count | read_skip_count | write_skip_count | exit_message |
| myItemSolrIndexStep      | 2016-05-12 10:07:01.994 | 2016-05-12 10:09:07.303 | COMPLETED | 279086     | 0            | 279086      | 0               | 0                |              |
```

And the `step_execution_context` database entry indicating that the reader has read `573937` rows

```
{"map":[{"entry":[{"string":"JdbcCursorItemReader.read.count","int":573937},{"string":["batch.taskletType","org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet"]},{"string":["batch.stepType","org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep"]}]}]}
```

A subsequent run results in the full `573937` records being processed, so this only happens intermittently. Any ideas for what might cause it, or methods for debugging the issue?

I can provide more detail if necessary

Comment: Could it be, that the run which had read only half of the entries was a restart of a previous run that already had read the other half? This could explain why the readcount has only 279086 entries despite the 573937 entries in the stepontext database table.

Comment: Thanks! That was it, I've disabled restartability and instead passing in a timestamp to the JobParameters so that it always ends up with a unique job id